# I want api to calculate distance from address to another address with here maps

Tags: node.js, here-api

why here maps is good better than google maps and
I want api to create distance from address to another address with here maps

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you've done, where you're stuck, expected vs actual results, errors, etc. Unfortunately, as written, this question is off-topic as "too broad" (it's a requirement, with many potential ways to implement an API). Also, you tagged this with `mongodb` and it's unclear how that is related to your question.

Answer (score -1):

I have no experience using the "Here Maps". I prefer you to check the official documentation since they have almost well-written documentation on their website.

For calculating the distance you can refer to this [link here](https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/resource-calculate-route.html) (Official docs)

Comment: full api  because i new with here maps

Comment: Please don't post a link-only answer; the documentation is readily available and findable via web search. Also: The OP's question, as written, is unclear and broad: it's just a requirement, with no specific programming question. Better to comment on the question itself to get clarification.